# Javascript multiple conditionals?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, binding, knockout.js, conditional-statements

So with Knockout I can show text based on if a condition returns true or false like this:

```
data-bind="text: status==0 ? 'Sent' : 'Failed'"
```

However, I need to add another condition, so that if `status==1` then it returns `Pending`.  I guess this probably just a general JS question vs Knockout.

Anyway, is it possible to do something like that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you really want to use Knockout's [Computed Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html). This will allow you to return different computed values based on your status.

```
function ViewModel() {
  this.status = ko.observable();
  this.statusText = ko.computed(function() {
    if (this.status() == 0) {
      return 'sent'
    } else {
      return 'failed';
  }, this);
}
```

Comment: That's what it was!!  I could've sworn there was a way to use a function in a binding like that, I just couldn't find it again.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: No prob. Just updated the answer because I submitted before I finished my code example.

Comment: Also the logic is moved to the VM, much cleaner